# Using the ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel with output caching

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, outputcache

Is there a way to have the UpdatePanel control play nicely with output caching?  I'd like to cache an entire ASP.NET page using the @OutputCache directive, EXCEPT for the UpdatePanel area.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the asp:substitution control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228212(v=vs.100).aspx